# Rounded Edge shape button not displaying on device

Tags: java, android, xml, drawable

I've been working on this temperature converter application on Android Studio and I am struggling to make a rounded edge button. I've done my research and using XML file to the drawable is the best option I have. However, I am planning to tweak this not in the main activity xml file but through JAVA (Since I want the button shape to change to the rounded box shape when individually clicked)

Right now, part of my Main activity java looks something like

```
mmBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                mmSelectedClicked[0] = true;
                cmSelectedClicked[0] = false;
                kmSelectedClicked[0] = false;
                miSelectedClicked[0] = false;
                mSelectedClicked[0] = false;
                ydSelectedClicked[0] = false;
                inSelectedClicked[0] = false;

                kmBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFFFF"));
                cmBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFFFF"));
                miBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFFFF"));
                mBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFFFF"));
                ydBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFFFF"));
                inBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFFFF"));
                if(mmSelectedClicked[0] == true){
                    view.setBackground(ColorDrawable.createFromPath("roundbutton"));
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            HscrollView1.smoothScrollTo((int) mmBtn.getX() - 150, 0);
                        }
                    }, 500);
                } else {
                    }
            }
        });
```

I've implemented :

```
view.setBackground(ColorDrawable.createFromPath("roundbutton"));
```

to change the background (drawable) to the "roundbutton.xml" under drawable folder.

App works with no crashes, however, the button background is displayed in a color-less bordered rectangular boxes which I didn't set so in my "roundbutton.xml".

[image]

As seen above, when I initialize my app, xml(drawable)-applied buttons show as the left button box (mm millimetre) with ugly border line. (fyi, the right button is non-xml applied button, but that should be the color it should show up as according to roundbutton.xml.

In my Android Studio preview, box seems to show as described (fully colored too, not a white box)in my roundbutton.xml, but on my actual app, it won't show up.

My roundbutton xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
    <!-- you can use any color you want I used here gray color-->
    <solid android:color="#CEF8D6"/>
    <corners android:radius="10dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

I'd like to have my drawable image as a background of a button, and when I press other buttons, it will go back to normal #FFFFFFFF.

I'd greatly appreciate it if you have a solution to this problem. :-)

Comment: Only android:radius="10dp" is enought in corners

Comment: view.setBackground(ColorDrawable.createFromPath("roundbutton")); statement is wrong. you can set it like view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundbutton);

Answer (score 0):

You can try with state selectors ....

Create new file **selectors.xml** in your drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/roundbutton" />
   <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/roundbutton" />
   <item android:state_focused="false" android:drawable="@color/defaultColorWhite" />
   <item android:drawable="@color/defaultColorWhite" />
</selector>
```

and at your button put

```
<button
.....

android:background:@drawable/selectors
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need set `size` item in the shape!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
    <!-- you can use any color you want I used here gray color-->
    <solid android:color="#CEF8D6"/>
    <corners android:radius="10dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
    <size android:width=xxdp
          android:height=xxdp/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this (increased the radius)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
    <!-- you can use any color you want I used here gray color-->
    <solid android:color="#CEF8D6"/>
    <corners android:radius="30dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="30dp"
        android:topRightRadius="30dp"/>
</shape>
```